# Xdebug installed, won't work on Linux Mint11

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to cross to mint11, but xampp installation is giving me a headache!!

So I installed xampp, then installed xdebug, via xdebug pages, (i went with tailored installation, so my xdebug file is ok). I try to debug in NetBeans and nothing, it says waiting for connection. I can see that it is installed via phpinfo(), but when i try to hit

```
$php -i | grep xdebug
```

the output tells me that `remote_enabled` is off, although i edited it in php.ini. 
Also, i get this in the beginning :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Comment: check that the ini file is pointing to a valid library

Comment: you mean my .so file or?

Comment: well, that makes the two uf us! :) @hakre : thank you for editing!

Answer (score 0):

> the [phpinfo()] output tells me that `remote_enabled` is off, although i edited it in php.ini.

You need to enable that [`remote_enabled` setting](http://xdebug.org/docs/remote), otherwise it won't work with NetBeans.

It's most likely you are editing the wrong php ini file.

The `mysql*.so` errors you see are most likely not related to xdebug, locate the lines in the diverse .ini files that are scanned and comment those so you don't get distracted by that error.

Then locate the right place where to configure xdebug, most likely in:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Comment: wait, so i edit the php.ini file, add the necessary lines, and then add them also in xdebug.ini?

Comment: No, just edit xdebug.ini for xdebug related settings. Don't edit php.ini at all, remove the xdebug setting from there if you already put them there. Move them over to xdebug.ini. That's the clean way and it ensures that things are kept in order.

Comment: so, i copied : zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable= On
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_log = /var/log/xdebug.log => /var/log/xdebug.log
to xdebug.ini, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: still nothing. i still get waiting for connection in netbeans. and also, when i try to run it, in firefox it says object not found. my path is correct i assume : http://localhost/NetBeansProjects/test1/index.php

Comment: not anymore. it showed while i had the settings in php.ini, but not that i removed them it doesn't.

Comment: you have the settings in xdebug.ini?

Comment: yes i do, and i also put them back in php.ini and now i can see it in phpinfo()

Comment: Then stick with php.ini, but your grep showed that xdebug.ini is loaded as well, so I wonder. Anyway, the Netbeans problem you have is then something else, check all the related questions on the right, you should find the insights you're missing. Check as well the link in my answer which has a nice description how it works.